# Placing iAd over UITabBar in a UITableView, Objective-C & TableView not appearing beneath iAd

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, iad

I am trying to get a similar result to the post that is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866171/place-iad-over-a-uitabbar

So this is what i did to achieve this:

[image]

One side question here: Is it normal that i can't drag the banner all the way?

And using this i get this result:

[image]

Nevermind that the iAd dont show. But my real question is why is not the TableView appearing beneath the iAd so i can get the same result as the on in the post? What can i do to make this work?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved this with some more researching and testing.

FIRST OF ALL. You **DONT** need to use a UITableView inside a UIViewController to make this work. This can be done by having a subclass of UITableViewController which i had from start but i thought i needed to change.

Anyway Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

NOTE this method is used when i am not placing an iAd in the storyboard. There is no need to do that when using this method. So no need to think about putting delegates etc..